# sum loop price and quantity input rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, sum

i have image like this

[image: 1]

i want to sum each rows Amount calculated from **price** * **quantity**, but when i input price and quantity each rows is form amount not filled

i try loop each rows and get value like this

```
function total_amount(){
    var table = document.getElementById('line_item');
    let qty = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
    let unit = document.getElementById('unit').value;
    var cellCount = table.rows[0].cells.length; 
    total =0 
    for(var i=0;i<table.rows.length;i++){
        let total = qty[i] * unit[i];
        document.getElementById('amount').value = total;    
        
    }
}
```

This is my html :

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="line_item" data-togle="table" data-sort-stable="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Product
      </th>
      <th>
        Quantity
      </th>
      <th>
        Price Unit
      </th>
      <th>
        Amount
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="col0">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Product">
      </td>
      <td id="col1">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" id="quantity" onblur="total_amount()">
      </td>
      <td id="col2">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Price Unit" id="unit" onblur="total_amount()">
      </td>
      <td id="col3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Amount" id="amount" readonly>
      </td>
      <td id="col4">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" aria-label="Delete" id="delete" onclick="delete_item()">
          <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but **Amount** not filled,

i expecting each rows amount is **SUM** from each price * quantity, how to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: This is hard to answer without the correlating HTML. Please update your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: hm, `let qty = document.getElementById('quantity').value` returns a single value. What would `qty[i]` mean then? Even if you have multiple elements with the same `id` (which is bad!) `getElementById` will select only one of them ...

Comment: I believe you are having multiple values with the same id, and that is a no go. Also please add your rendered html so we can help you

Comment: i have been updated my question with html code,please help me

Comment: @BimoAnugrahPrasetyo remove your for loop and do `let total = qty * unit;`

Comment: if remove for loop i just sum 1 line rows, but i have multiple line

Comment: i have remove loop but, stil sum 1 line, not multiple line @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
function total_amount(){
        var table = document.getElementById('line_item');
        for(var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++){
            qty = table.rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
            unit = table.rows[i].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
            table.rows[i].cells[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = qty * unit;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you are move rows, that means you most likely have multiple elements with the same id.

You can do it like this:

```
function total_amount(ele) {
  var tr = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
  let qty = tr.querySelector('.quantity').value;
  let unit = tr.querySelector('.unit').value;
  let total = qty * unit;
  tr.querySelector('.amount').value = total;
}
```

Then on your input's I've added `this` to the function and remove the id to the class

```
<input class="form-control quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" id="" onblur="total_amount(this)">
```

```js
function total_amount(ele) {
  var tr = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
  let qty = tr.querySelector('.quantity').value;
  let unit = tr.querySelector('.unit').value;
  let total = qty * unit;
  tr.querySelector('.amount').value = total;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="line_item" data-togle="table" data-sort-stable="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Product
      </th>
      <th>
        Quantity
      </th>
      <th>
        Price Unit
      </th>
      <th>
        Amount
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="col0">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Product">
      </td>
      <td id="col1">
        <input class="form-control quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" id="" onblur="total_amount(this)">
      </td>
      <td id="col2">
        <input class="form-control unit" type="number" placeholder="Price Unit" id="" onblur="total_amount(this)">
      </td>
      <td id="col3">
        <input class="form-control amount" type="number" placeholder="Amount" id="" readonly>
      </td>
      <td id="col4">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" aria-label="Delete" id="delete" onclick="delete_item()">
          <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="col0">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Product">
      </td>
      <td id="col1">
        <input class="form-control quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" id="" onblur="total_amount(this)">
      </td>
      <td id="col2">
        <input class="form-control unit" type="number" placeholder="Price Unit" id="" onblur="total_amount(this)">
      </td>
      <td id="col3">
        <input class="form-control amount" type="number" placeholder="Amount" id="" readonly>
      </td>
      <td id="col4">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" aria-label="Delete" id="delete" onclick="delete_item()">
          <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Good morning.

First of all, in your HTML code you have only one tr and if your app can have more than one td (I think that is in the most cases) you have to create a class instead an id that can iterate in the elements (have one id for more than one element it's a bad practice).

In this case I think you have to detect changes in both inputs, validate the inputs and finally do the calc.

I provide an example for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/wngshzrv/23/

```html
 <table class="table table-striped" id="line_item" data-togle="table" data-sort-stable="true">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    Product
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Quantity
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Price Unit
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Amount
                  </th>
              
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="product">
                  <td class="col0">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Product" >
                  </td>
                  <td class="col1">
                    <input class="form-control quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity"  >
                  </td>
                  <td class="col2">
                    <input class="form-control unit" type="number" placeholder="Price Unit"  >
                  </td>
                  <td class="col3">
                    <input class="form-control amount" type="number" placeholder="Amount"  readonly>
                  </td>
                  <td class="col4">
                  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" aria-label="Delete" id="delete" onclick="delete_item()">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                  </button>
                  </td>
                
                </tr>          
                <tr class="product">
                  <td class="col0">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Product" >
                  </td>
                  <td class="col1">
                    <input class="form-control quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity">
                  </td>
                  <td class="col2">
                    <input class="form-control unit" type="number" placeholder="Price Unit"  >
                  </td>
                  <td class="col3">
                    <input class="form-control amount" type="number" placeholder="Amount"  readonly>
                  </td>
                  <td class="col4">
                  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" aria-label="Delete" id="delete" onclick="delete_item()">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                  </button>
                  </td>
                
                </tr>    
              </tbody>
            </table>
<script>
var products = document.querySelectorAll(".product")

products.forEach(x=>{
var quantity = x.querySelector(".col1 .quantity")
var priceUnit = x.querySelector(".col2 .unit")
var amount = x.querySelector(".col3 .amount")
priceUnit.addEventListener('blur',()=>{
    amount.value = quantity.value*priceUnit.value
})

})
</script>
```

You only have to validate the numbers.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: i can add line dynamic when i click the button add item, how to your code handle this ?

Comment: You have to detect changes on the dom and iterate the line added.

Answer (score -2):

use this function

```
function total_amount(){
  var table = document.getElementById('line_item');
  let qty = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
  let unit = document.getElementById('unit').value;
  var cellCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  total =0
  for(var i=0;i<table.rows.length;i++){
    if (qty[i] && unit[i] && !isNaN(Number(qty[i])) && !isNaN(Number(unit[i])) ){
      let total = Number(qty[i]) * Number(unit[i]);
      document.getElementById('amount').value = total; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If user enters the value `12` into quantity field , and then you do `Number(qty[i])`, then you get `1` and not `12`

Comment: i have try your code, but is just sum 1 rows, when i click add item rows can bee add dynamicly,

Comment: @BimoAnugrahPrasetyo Look at my last comment to your question, remove the loop